# MouseEventArgs Location wrong when use sizemode fit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a rectangle, when I click on this, this will display to another view

I'm using Rectangle.Contains(e.Location) (e is MouseEventArgs)
This is ok when SizeMode is normal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydQCn.png

But when I set the display SizeMode to fit, the Rectangle has to go to another location, but I must click on old location same as SizeMode normal
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUPsC.png

I think I need scale rectangle when go to fit mode, but I don't know the ratio. Please help me

Comment: Users can't tell that you are talking about PictureBox.  The mapping function [is here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,5c2ab37313f547c2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calulate the ratio of rectangle, you could calculate ratio =  Width / Height

So width and height are always linked by this formula, if you want to keep the same ratio

if you know the new width,  new height = new width / ratio

or

if you know the new height, new width = ratio * new height

Comment: Thanks, I was done this with this code:

var p1 = e.Location;
var p5 = new Point( p1.X * imageViewer.Image.Width / this.imageViewer.Width
     , p1.Y * imageViewer.Image.Height / this.imageViewer.Height );
var b5 = myRectangle.Contains( p5 ); =>true

Answer (score 1):

You might need to map the screen co-ordinates to control co-ordinates. Take a look at the helper [PointToClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient?view=netframework-4.7.2).